# Wordpress author page, change menu parent

Tags: wordpress, author

I have an Author page on my Wordpress site (author.php). The problem though is that when im visiting the author page, Wordpress highlights the blog menu item. I want to have another menu item as parent. How do I go about it? I dont want to use no JS/jQuery for this.

Thanks

Comment: can you share the page link.

Comment: Is your author page looks like http://demo.wphelper.de/author/themedemos/

Comment: I cannot share the page link unfortunately since its one of my customers website. But the author page contains the author profile information followed by the authors most recent posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear that how your author page url looks like. In general its like site url/author/"author name".

If your site has a single author then you can add the author page link as a custom menu item .

Or you can use jQuery function to search "author" in your url and add active class in desired menu item

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
if(if(window.location.href.indexOf("author") > -1)) 
{
     $("#author_menu").addClass('active');
}
 });
</script>
```

Not the cleanest solution, but I use something like this for a few instances of current page menu highlighting for pages that aren't child/parent related in any way:

```
 <?php if (is_author()) { ?>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#menu-main-menu li.menu-item-"**about_us_page_class**"').addClass('current-menu-item');
  }); });
 </script>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: The url looks like this: domain.com/author/author-name. All I want to do is make the "About us" menu item active whenever an authors page is viewed. I prefer not to use JS or jQ though. HTML/PHP/CSS is preferred. Thanks!

Comment: I have added another solution , may be it will help you or you need to use add_filter('nav_menu_css_class' , 'some_function' , 10 , 2) Hook .

Comment: Yes, I like the add_filter solution better. I still need some help though to understand what my function should return in order to get this to work. Thanks.